# Summing rows only of a 2D array and putting the sum into a new array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I need to fix the code below to take the sum of the values in the rows of the 2D array and put them in a new array. I have tried a bunch of different ways, but just can't seem to figure out how to get it right.

The issue is in the hoursArray method:

```
//Bronson Lane 4/18
//This program computes employee's weekly hours and sorts them in descending order
package hw12;
import java.util.*;

public class HW12 {
    public static double[][] hoursArray(double[][] weeklyHours) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[][] total = new double[weeklyHours.length][];
        //double sum[][] = new double[weeklyHours.length][];

        for (int row = 0; row < weeklyHours.length; row++) {
            total = total[row][];
            for (int column = 0; column < weeklyHours[row].length; column++) {
                total = total + weeklyHours[row][column];

            }
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static void selectionSort(double[][] list) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] weeklyHours = {{2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8},
                {7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4},
                {3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2},
                {9, 3, 4, 7, 3, 4, 1},
                {3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8},
                {3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4},
                {3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 8, 4},
                {6, 3, 5, 9, 2, 7, 9}};
        double cool = hoursArray(weeklyHours);

        System.out.println(cool);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems vedy close to matrix multiplication to me.

Comment: Homework part 12? What have you tried and where do you get stuck? Quick hint, the total arrays needs to be of type `double[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let's think about your question carefully, you want your function to get a 2d array and output an array so first your function `hoursArray` should return `double[]` not `double[][]`.

Now what size should the output array have ? if the 2d array is of size n*m then the output array should have n elements since it's the rows what we want to sum, so we instantiate total to `total=new double[weeklyhours.length]`.

Now we loop every row of `weeklyhours` and sum them, but how ?

Remember that 2d arrays are actually array of arrays, each row is an array and if you know how to sum an array then this is the same, the difference is where we put the sum.

In 1d arrays sum we write : `sum+= a[i]` in a for loop, here we write `sum[row]+=a[row][i]`, `i` is almost the same , the difference is the addition of `row`.

Because we want to do the sum of 1d array for each row we have two for-loops : one that loops the rows and another one is for looping the elements of the array of the row.

when the outside for-loop ends, we return `sum` which is a 1d array, exactly what we intended to do.

Putting all these pieces together we end with this code :

```
static double[] hoursArray(double[][] weeklyhours)
{
    double[] sum=new double[weeklyhours.length]
    for(int row=0;row < sum.length;row++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<weeklyhours[row].length;i++)
            sum[row]+=weeklyhours[row][i]
    }
    return sum;
}
```

### Note:

Your function should take input and produce output, from where does that input come must be decided in the `main` or any function you decide to handle input with, `hoursArray` should not read `weeklyhours` from user when it's getting it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

i chnaged a little in your code test this

```
public static double[] hoursArray(double[][] weeklyHours) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] total = new double[weeklyHours.length];
    //double sum[][] = new double[weeklyHours.length][];

    for (int row = 0; row < weeklyHours.length; row++) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int column = 0; column < weeklyHours[row].length; column++) {
            sum += weeklyHours[row][column];
        }
        total[row] = sum;
    }
    return total;
}

public static void selectionSort(double[][] list) {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] weeklyHours = {{2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8},
            {7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4},
            {3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2},
            {9, 3, 4, 7, 3, 4, 1},
            {3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8},
            {3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4},
            {3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 8, 4},
            {6, 3, 5, 9, 2, 7, 9}};

    double cool[] = hoursArray(weeklyHours);
    for(double co : cool){
        System.out.print(co + ",");
    }
}
```